# Facebook social plugins - Comments for mutiple pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I need to design a site where each product has a Facebook comment box. As far as I understand, it is possible to have a Facebook page related to a given URL, and the comments for the box on that URL will also appear on the Facebook page.

My problem is slightly different: I would need to have a Facebook page, where all the comments for the various products should be collected together. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the comments for each product page to be unique and then "collected together" on a Facebook page -- its not possible.

It is possible to have the comments plugin for every product page be the same comments that are on the Facebook page, but then the comments on each product page would not be unique. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly as I imagined.